# Cannot send more than 4 files with dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, dropzone.js

This is weird...

I can send 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 files with dropzone but cannot send 5 or more..

I suppose I am correctly defining the options here:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: "action.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 6,
    maxFilesize: 5, 
    maxFiles: 6,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    paramName: 'userfile',
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Too many files! Maximum is {{maxFiles}}',

    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.
        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("submit-form").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            // If the user has selected at least one file, AJAX them over.
            if (dzClosure.files.length !== 0) {
                // dzClosure.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
                dzClosure.processQueue();
            // Else just submit the form and move on.
            } else {
                $('#foorm').submit();
            }
        });
        // send all the form data along with the files:
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("name", $("#name").val());
            formData.append("email", $("#email").val());
        }); 
        this.on("sucessmultiple", function(files, response) {
            // dzClosure.options.autoProcessQueue = false;
            $(location).attr('href', 'message_sent.html')
        });
    }
}
```

I say correctly because when I drag more than 6 files I see the error message: `Too many files! Maximum is 6`

Does this boundary make any sense in the source code?

Some more details:
a simplified version of my form is as follows

```
<form id="foorm" method="post" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
    <button type="submit" name="submit-form" id="submit-form">Send!</button>
</form>
```

and my `action.php` starts with displaying `json_encode($_FILES);` and `json_encode($_POST);`

and they are as expected when sending less than 4 files and are `[]` when sending 5 or more

EDIT

It seems that I can upload 5 or more if they are smaller in size! Can this be anything else than a bug on dropzone? (honest question)

Comment: Are you sure one of your test files isn't over the 5MB limit and gets rejected because of that?

Comment: @KScandrett I was sure, but still went there and checked! And now I'm even more sure that none of my files are above the limit (they are around 2 MB each). But.. you made me consider if the total size of the files would be a factor, and it is!!! I found that I can upload much more pictures if they are much smaller (like 1KB each)!! weird! ... first thing I tried was to increase maxFilesize to a very big number and see if I can upload 5 2MB pictures, and I can't! Does this shine some light on what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a recent comment, the problem seems to be that you're limited by the PHP file upload settings.

Increase `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`. The default is "2M" (2Mb).

You'll likely also need to increase `post_max_size`, which has a default of "8M". And don't forget to restart your HTTP server.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads

Comment: It is indeed!!! Thank you! I had already changed the `upload_max_filesize`, but I didn't read about changing `post_max_size` which makes total sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set `uploadMultiple` to `false`, `autoProcessQueue` to `true`

Put the following event to `init` to set how much you can upload

```
this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
  if (this.files[10] != null) {
    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
  }
});
this.on('maxfilesreached', function(file) {
  if (this.files[10] != null) {
    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
  }
});
```

#### Full Code:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  url: "action.php",
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  maxFilesize: 5,
  maxFiles: 10,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  method: 'put',
  dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Too many files! Maximum is {{maxFiles}}',
  init: function() {
    this.on('processing', function(file) {
      data = file;
      console.log(this.options.url);
    });
    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
      if (this.files[10] != null) {
        this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
    this.on('maxfilesreached', function(file) {
      if (this.files[10] != null) {
        this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
    this.on('success', function(file, resp) {
      if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
          setTimeout(function () {
             console.log('all are uploaded');
          }, 500);
      }
    });
    this.on("error", function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
      alert(file.name + ": " + errorMessage)
    });
    this.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
      alert("queuecomplete");
    });
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
      var _send = xhr.send;
      xhr.send = function() {
        _send.call(xhr, file);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting `autoProcessQueue` to `true` would not work for me as I just want the files to be sent when the user hits submit. right?

Comment: @NunoCalaim hm, you have a submit button for img? or submit the form?

Comment: @NunoCalaim could be a race condition you have, while your img are uploading, your submit already completed?

Comment: my submit button works as follows: first you fill in the form, then you choose the files, then you click submit, then the files start uploading and after that I send the rest of the form fields. My php script then will email me with all the details and all the files in attachment.

Comment: @NunoCalaim hm, you redirect the user once `queuecomplete`? I think you might want to move that to `success`, try my code for the `success` event

Comment: @NunoCalaim also you can try to add a `setTimeout` wrap your redirect call, set a 0.5 sec delay, this is just to debug to find out why it is not working

Answer (score -1):

just set the `parallelUploads` parameter same as the value of `maxFiles` option

Comment: Does not solve the problem.. because those options already have the same value of `6` (as you can see from my post)